# How do I add more than one of an ingredient?

Tags: cook-serve-delicious

I noticed when people ask for soup, there is usually a number beside each vegetable. I assume I need to add that vegetable that number of times, but I can't figure out how to actually do that, and it seems like my soup eaters are always unhappy with their soup.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to cut ingredient certain number of times with Kinfe Cut command.
ie. Like in case of screenshot that I uploaded, where you have to add 3 slices of tomato.
You pick tomato (with 'T') and then press three times knife cut ('down arrow')

[image: Cooking soup]

If I'm not wrong after 3 cuts Knife cut should turn inactive again and you can pick new ingredient to add.
You can also practice how to make certain food from Management->View/Buy food